# How to stop Unity on the phone so it doesn't restart?

Tags: unity, ubuntu-touch, qt

How to bring down the Ubuntu Phone GUI so I can test some Qt stuff?

I figured that it's easy to put arbitrary Qt versions into home dir and run them without messing with the main installation. But I failed to make them use the Mir integration (`libqpa-ubuntumirclient.so`):

> This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "ubuntumirclient".

The eglfs mode works fine, except it's fighting with Unity for the GL.

**update**

Stopped `lightdm`, it turned off the screen so no one gets it...